# Splitting a data set using two parameters and saving the sub-data sets in a list

Tags: r

I am trying to split my data set using two parameters, the fraction of missing values and "maf", and store the sub-data sets in a list. Here is what I have done (it's not working).  Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks.

```
 library(BLR)
 library(missForest)
 data(wheat)

 X2<- prodNA(X, 0.4) ### creating missing values
 dim(X2)

 fd<-t(X2)  

 MAF<-function(geno){        ## markers are in the rows
 geno[(geno!=0) & (geno!=1) & (geno!=-1)] <- NA
 geno <- as.matrix(geno)
 ## calc_Freq for alleles
 n0 <- apply(geno==0,1,sum,na.rm=T)
 n1 <- apply(geno==1,1,sum,na.rm=T)
 n2 <- apply(geno==-1,1,sum,na.rm=T)
 n <- n0 + n1 + n2
 ## calculate allele frequencies
 p <- ((2*n0)+n1)/(2*n)
 q <- 1 - p
 maf  <- pmin(p, q)
 maf}

 frac.missing <- apply(fd,1,function(z){length(which(is.na(z)))/length(z)})

 maf<-MAF(fd)

 lst<-matrix()
 for (i in seq(0.2,0.7,by =0.2)){
 for (j in seq(0,0.2,by =0.005)){
 lst=fd[(maf>j)|(frac.missing < i),]
 }}
```

Comment: What is MAF? Could you include a small portion of your data in your post?  And what is frac.missing?

Comment: Hi Mark: maf ( is the minor allele frequency), it is function. My only problem is with saving the results in a list (lst).

Comment: That is not your only problem. The expression `maf`  will not return numeric values unless it is called with arguments in a form like this: `maf(arg)`. Another problem is that you are overwriting the value of `lst` every time you go through the loop. And a final problem is lack of clarity on whether you want overlapping values in the elements of `lst` which is what the current code threatens to produce if you ever correct the first two errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below codes give me exactly what i need:

```
Y<-t(GBS.binary)
nn<-colnames(Y)
fd<-Y
maf<-as.matrix(MAF(Y))
dff<-cbind(frac.missing,maf,Y)
colnames(dff)<-c("fm","maf",nn)
dff<-as.data.frame(dff)

for (i in seq(0.1,0.6,by=0.1)) { 
       for (j in seq(0,0.2,by=0.005)){  
              assign(paste("fm_",i,"maf_",j,sep=""),
                     (subset(dff, maf>j & fm <i))[,-c(1,2)])
                                }    }
```

Comment: So you were willing to have all of the items that ended up in `maf_0.1_fm0.1`  also be in `maf_0.05_fm0.1` and for all the items in `maf_0.05_fm0.1` to be in `maf_0_fm0.1`? If that really the case then you certainly do not want `split` and even using the word "split" was misleading most of your audience. "Split" means to separate into disjoint groupings.

Comment: Sorry, for the misleading information! do you have any idea how to make the above codes more efficient, please? this is very critical step for me, specially when we change the values,  and will be repeated several times using different data sets.thank you again for your time and help

Comment: for (i in seq(0.1,0.6,by=0.1)) {
for (j in seq(0,0.2,by=0.005)){
   assign(paste("fm_",i,"maf_",j,sep=""),(subset(dff, maf>j & fm <i))[,-c(1,2)])

}}

Comment: I do not see that the modifications change the behavior of the code. The first pass will still assign a larger group to fm_1maf_1 than it does to later assigned variables. And  later groups will still have rows that are contained in all the earlier groups. Yet you say is is behaving properly, so I think it is premature to attempt more efficiency. The `cut` and `findInterval` functions provide mechanisms for "splitting" but it remains unclear whether you actually want to "split", because you appear to be making a problem specification using a language (R) that you do not understand.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want the results that the `split` function provides.

If you have a vector, "frac.missing" and "maf" is defined on the basis of values in "fd" (and has the same length as the number of rows in fd"), then this would provide the split you are looking for:

```
  spl.fd <- split(fd, list(maf, frac.missing) )
```

If you want to "group" the `fd` values basesd on of `maf(fd)` and `frac.missing` within the bands specified by your for-loop, then the same `split`-construct may do what your current code is failing to accomplish:

```
lst <- split( fd, list(cut(maf(fd), breaks = seq(0,0.2,by =0.005) , 
                                       include.lowest=TRUE), 
                       cut(frac.missing, breaks = seq(0.2,0.7,by =0.2),
                             right=TRUE,include.lowest=TRUE)
                        )
              )
```

The right argument accomodates the desire to have the splits based on a "<" operator whereas the default operation of `cut` presumes a ">" comparison against the 'breaks'. The other function that provides similar facility is `by`.

Comment: Hi DWin: i am not using attach... maf and frac.missing are two functions (not variables) that i applied on the data frame (fd). and i am trying to use different cutoff from both maf and frac.missing to create sub data sets to be used with lapply. anyway thank you

Comment: If they were functions, then you could not use expressions like `maf>j` , since `maf` has not been given an argument. You would need to pass some vector or some other data-object to `maf`. But if they are vectors (as they appear to be), and they both had length equal to the number of rows in `fd`, then you should definitely try spl.fd <- split(fd, list(maf, frac.missing) )

Comment: Yes, I did see the edtited material. THAT was why I modified my answer. You still cannot compare a function name to an index! They are not comparable with R operators. I'm getting close to voting to close because you are not willing to read for meaning.

Comment: Dear DWin: thank you for your help. As you can see in the question i am trying to loop over the two functions using different ratios of the missing values and maf, but your answer simply assume i have only one value for each of them, right?   again thank you

Comment: My answer assumes that `maf` (if called as a function which at the moment is not the case)  will return a vector which is the same length as the number of rows in `fd`.

Comment: Hi i tried your codes,  but the names for the data sets looks weird,  > names(lst)
 [1] "[0,0.005].[0.2,0.4]"  "(0.005,0.01].[0.2,0.4]" "(0.01,0.015].[0.2,0.4]" "(0.015,0.02].[0.2,0.4]" "(0.02,0.025].[0.2,0.4]"

Comment: Please do not focus on trivialities. Is the data and the data layout correct?

Comment: DWi: thank you for you answer. I cannot see the rownames or the colnames, i seriously cannot tell.